# What does this Unicode Escape error mean?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

When i try to run this code:

```
import os
  
path = "C:\Users\\"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
  
print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :") 
print(dir_list)
```

I get this error:
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' coded can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

What does it mean? How can i fix it?

Instead of printing the contents it just gives me this error every time.

Comment: It means `\Users` is not a valid Unicode character; the correct syntax only allows 8 hex digits after `\U`, like `\U0001F4A9` for [](https://emojis.wiki/pile-of-poo/). You clearly meant `\\Users`

Comment: Try using path as `path = "C:\\Users"` or `path = "C:/Users"`